# Wordpress Return-Path not working only for forms while works when testing using WP-MAIL-SMTP

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I'm having Wordpress-Form-Manager plugin to create forms.

I'm using Wp-Mail-Smtp plugin to send smtp emails from wordpress.

I've setup the smtp(gmail) details inside the plugin settings page, and i tested the settings from the form given to check whether i receive the email.

Testing email successfully received with the Return-Path as my gmail username,

But when i submit a form generated, the return-path is domain@domain.com in the email that is  received. No matter what i change the code manually or try with someother plugin nothing works!!

Solutions Tried :

1. Set manually $phpmailer->Sender name in functions.php page and add action to phpmailer_init
2. Add the same into pluggable.php inside wp_mail() function.
3. Use email-return-path-fix plugin
4. try adding the above plugin code directly into functions.php

None of the above worked, and also i googled so long from which i didnt came across anyone facing the same issue.

Most weird thing is, it works perfectly when i use "Send a Test Email" form below the settings page but it doesn't work from the forms in the website.

Kindly help me on setting the Return-Path same like my from address.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail **forbids** overriding the Return-Path header. And why would you want to?? It's for [bounce emails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: What are you talking about? There was no question. There was a request. It was "Kindly help me on setting the Return-Path same like my from address." ... With Gmail. I told him its not possible ... With Gmail. How is that not an answer?

Comment: It is an automatic connect left during review. Someone flagged your submission and while reviewing it seemed to me that the asker has not explicitly required the use of Gmail. Perhaps you can expand on this answer a bit.